# Issues with alternate Windows software and Wine

Tags: wine, configuration, playonlinux

I am running a non-popular windows software with PlayOnLinux and numerical fields like **currency/monetary** has an error with **duplicated decimal separators**.

Numbers are displayed as follows *(with Brazilian locale)*:

> ,200,00

And, if I change Ubuntu's locale settings *(to US locale, for example)*:

> .200.00

**My question is:** How can I solve this problem? **or** Where can I ask this question if AskUbuntu isn't the right place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WineHQ.com](http://www.winehq.com) is the place to report such issues.

Open a ticket on the site and let the developers help you with your situation.

Comment: Issue reported. http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?p=78355

I have tried everything. Now just cross our fingers and wait.